# «Может быть» — сказуемое или вводное слово?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, грамматика, вводные-слова, сложное-предложение

> Может быть(,) потому как раз, что катки были открытые?

В данном случае ***может быть*** — это сказуемое или вводное слово?
Если вводное, то какая же тогда грамматическая основа в первой части?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для того, чтобы ответить однозначно, нужно рассмотреть [контекст](https://www.tulup.ru/articles/320/ehti_starye_dobrye_vremena.html).

> Выступали кто в чем. Рейтузы вязали телесного цвета. Это к тому же было практично: ведь мы же в основном на открытых катках катались. Какие раньше были морозы! Почему? **Может быть, потому как раз, что катки были открытые?** Всегда в таких городах выступали, где морозы стояли лютые, в Кирово-Чепецке, Барнауле... (Л. А. Пахомова)

[**Может быть**](http://old-punctum.ru/punctum.php?sid=417), *вводное сочетание* (не слово!)
То же, что "вероятно", "возможно". Выделяется запятыми. Можно изъять из предложения.

[**Как ра́з**](https://classes.ru/all-russian/dictionary-ortho-term-29259.htm)
**2.** *частица разг.*
1) Употребляется при выделении, подчеркивании последующего слова; именно.
В этом предложении частица (ее тоже можно изъять из предложения) стоит **после** выделяемого слова.

*Какие раньше были морозы! Почему?* [Морозы были] ***Потому, что катки были открытые?*** — в этом вопросительном предложении (оно относится к [неполным](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/722-26_nepolnye_predlozheniya.html); вводное сочетание и усилительная частица отсутствуют) подлежащее и сказуемое по смыслу восстанавливаются из предыдущего контекста.